# decision of last hour

Tags: reference

Imagine, a decision is made. It was made no more than 1 hour ago.

What are all possible ways to refer to it if we want to use 'last hour'?

1. last hour decision
2. decision of last hour
3. I assume, 'decision in last hour' isn't correct because it means something else ?

Is 1 and 2 correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision was *made* **in the last hour**.  It *is* a decision **of the last hour**.

**in the last hour**  functions adverbally:

> When was the decision made?
>   -- In the last hour.

**of the last hour** functions adjectivally:

> To what part of the day (or of the crisis, project, operation, whatever) does the decision belong?
>   -- It is a decision of the last hour.